# Reusing Tasks (operators) across DAGs

Tags: airflow

I'm exploring AirFlow as a workflow execution engine.

I like the fact that it's very flexible, allow multiple operators, such as Python functions. However, I'm afraid I may be missing something fundamental - Task reuse. I want to run existing operators in multiple DAGs without having to redefine them.

As far as I can tell - this is not supported. Am I wrong? and If so, I'll be happy if someone can point me to a solution.

The only (awkward) solution that comes to mind is to have a dummy-DAG for every Operator, and then building my DAG on top of these dummy-DAGs with a *DagRunOperator*.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way to achieve this would be to create your own Airflow plugin.

(From the [Airflow Documentation on Plugins](https://airflow.apache.org/plugins.html))

> Airflow has a simple plugin manager built-in that can integrate external features to its core by simply dropping files in your $AIRFLOW_HOME/plugins folder.
>
> The python modules in the plugins folder get imported, and hooks, operators, sensors, macros, executors and web views get integrated to Airflow’s main collections and become available for use.

So if you were to create a custom operator in your plugin, you would be able to re-use that same operator across multiple DAGs.

This repo may also be helpful as it has quite a few examples of Airflow plugins: https://github.com/airflow-plugins

Comment: I dont know why this is thumbed down. This literally is the only possible answer